# Maximal area coverable by $k$ disjoint isosceles triangles contained in a triangle of area 1. 

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Given a triangle $\Delta$ of unit area, how much area can always be covered by $k$ isosceles triangles contained in $\Delta$ and intersecting at most at their boundaries?

The answer is easy for $k=1$. Without error of my part, the worst case is given by a triangle
with sides proportional to $1+\epsilon,2+\epsilon,3+\epsilon$ where one can cover roughly $2/3$ of the total area.

Is there an elegant way to compute the answer for $k=2,3,\dots$?

Comment: Can you say something about the motivation?

Comment: This is a kind of toy model for question  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22028/diameter-of-a-metric-on-orbits-under-affine-bijections-of-n-dimensional-convex which is (somewhat losely) related to question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3307/can-a-discrete-set-of-the-plane-of-uniform-density-intersect-all-large-triangles

Answer (score 10):

**Three trivial observations (not an answer)**.

Let us denote by $a_k(\Delta)$ the maximal covered area in $\Delta$.
Then

- for any right triangle $a_2=1$,
- for any acute triangle $a_3=1$,
- for any triangle $a_4=1$.

Comment: Nice observations!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can completely find those triangles for which  $a_{2}=1$.

We have two isosceles triangles forming a third triangle.
Two of their angles must form a 180 degree angle. the two
equal angles of both triangles cannot do this. So the vertex
angle of one triangle must be adjacent to one of the angles
of the second triangle. Let the second triangle have one angle
$A$ and two angles B=$90-A$. Then if the angle of the first
triangle is adjacent to $A$ then It must be of magnitude 180-$A$
and the other two angles of the triangle must be $A/2$ but we then must
add $A/2$ two one of the remaining angles this the triangle with the following
angles:

($A/2$, 90, $90-A/2$) this gives all right triangles which has already been noted in a separate answer.

If the angle of the first triangle is adjacent to $90-A/2$ then we get
a new angle of $45-A/4$ we will have to add this quantity to either
of the two angles giving two triangles with the following angles:

($45-A/4$, A, $135-3A/4$)

($45-A/4$, $90-A/2$, $45+3A/4$)

Comment: My question concerns the worst case.